# What is proper cmd. line invocation of the EOS cmd. "cleos set contract?"

Tags: eos

From the documentation at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cpp/docs/token-tutorial:

```
cleos set contract eosio.token build/contracts/eosio.token -p eosio.token@active
```

But from the documentation at https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-set-contract:

```
set contract (below are parameters:)
```

Positional Parameters:
account TEXT - The account to publish a contract for
wast-file TEXT - The file containing the contract WAST or WASM
abi-file TEXT - The ABI for the contract

So which is it? I'm confused b/c the documentatin is inconsistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is outdated. You can run `cleos set contract help` to see latest docs. It would result to:

- account — the account to publish a contract for.
- contract-dir — contract directory.
- wast-file — the file containing the contract WAST or WASM.
- abi-file — the ABI of the contract.

Also, if your wast/abi files have the same name as folder, you my specify only contract-dir.

"[How to Create and Deploy Your Own EOS Token](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-and-deploy-your-own-eos-token-1f4c9cc0eca1)" might be helpful.